# What is the exact relation between honeycomb atomic arrangement and Dirac cones?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, graphene

The question is in the title. I couldn't find any resembling question from the past.
Any link to thorough study (with the answer to my question) would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: This subject is way beyond me, but perhaps to clarify your question, I wonder have you seen this article and if it is the type of analysis you after http://www.nature.com/articles/srep18107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider graphene as a simple tight-binding model (only nearest neighbor hopping, no interactions) you can write down the Hamiltonian in second quantization and calculate the dispersion relation by diagonalizing said Hamiltonian. This is done by a transformation to momentum space. If you then expand the dispersion around a Dirac point (which are points in momentum space) you find a linear crossing ("Dirac cone"). See for example the second chapter in this paper for more information and plots of the dispersion relation: http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.109

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure this out within the paper. I mean what is special about the hexagonal lattice that it has such specific electronic structure regardless the type of atoms (C, Si, etc)

Comment: You might find this paper more fitting http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.035401 . It discusses the underlying lattice symmetries that can lead to Dirac cones.